# Application somehow writing unwanted parameters to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have two functions.  Both of them take a massive JSON object, and one of them changes it to the format:

```
[{ date: 'date', count_0: '10' },
 { date: 'date', count_0: '10' }]
```

The other function changes the JSON object to this format:

```
[{ date: 'date', count_0: '10', count_1: '20', count_2: '30' ... },
 { date: 'date', count_0: '10', count_1: '20', count_2: '30' ... }]
```

Here's the bizarre part.  **I'm only calling the first function, but my program is attempting to produce the format of the second function.**

The other function is in my code, but I know it's not being called because I have a number of `alert` functions inside it that are not firing.

**Here's a clarification to make my problem clearer.**  Below is the first function... a bunch of `(for... in)` junk and conditional statements:

```
function firstFunction(data, sort, campaign) {
  var transformed_data = [];

  // Loop through the original data
  for(var d in data) {
    var obj = data[d];

    // If you have the correct campaign data
    if(obj.name === campaign) {

      // For each data entry in this object
      for(var obj_d in obj.data) {
        var obj_data = obj.data[obj_d];

        // Create a temporary transformed object to hold the proper data
        var transformed_obj = {
          date: obj_data.date,
          count_0: obj_data[sort]
        }

        // This console log shows the transformed_obj in the expected format
        console.log(transformed_obj);

        // Push the temporary object into the helper array
        transformed_data.push(transformed_obj);

        // This console log flips a shit
        console.log(transformed_data);
      }
    }
  }
  // Return helper array
  return transformed_data;
}
```

The first console log in that function shows the proper format:

`Object {date: "2013-01-01", count_0: 17147}`

The second console log shows this:

`[Object]`

Okay, good so far... let's expand it...

**Expanded:**

```
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
```

What?  This isn't expected at all... wonder what happens if we expand one of those objects...

**Expanded object:**

```
count_0: 17147
count_1: NaN
count_2: NaN
count_3: NaN
count_4: NaN
count_5: NaN
date: Mon Dec 31 2012 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

What????  Why is it trying to write the properties `count_1` through `count_5`?  What could be the problem here?

---

#### Solved

My directive was trying to write properties to the array that didn't exist, and apparently the directive was firing before the controller.  Marking as closed.

Comment: Could you show some example data and function call so that we could try and see the result ourselves? It's a bit hard to debug if you can't try it.

Comment: I'll try to compile some and add it to the question.

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` loops to iterate through arrays. Use a plain `for` loop with an index variable or the `.forEach()` method (in newer browsers).

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj_data = obj.data[obj_data];
```

is destroying your loop "iterator."  Try using a different variable (e.g. var element = ).

Also, you tagged this question with jQuery - [why not embrace jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/each/)?

Comment: Nice find, I fixed the variable problem.  It's still trying to write multiple `count_i` things tho.

Comment: Good.  Go ahead and update your question.  Also, have you ever used jsFiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: See @Pointy's comment above.  An investment in learning jQuery loops will pay dividends.  :)

Comment: Yeah.  I've used JSFiddle before, I'm trying to make one right now but there are a lot of Angular dependencies and stuff.  It's not working out.

Comment: I think you'll need to add the second function and show how you're calling them.